# adding angular code within html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in Angular this would be allowed:

```
{{ 5 + 5 }}
```

but something like this cannot

```
{{ angular.forEach(something, function(item){
 console.log(item._id);
}); }}
```

But I really want such a thing to work, because I want to combine ng-repeat while validating certain values.
If I validate it with code in the controller, it's doesn't keep track of new changes. It doesn't bind real time, I would need the page to refresh.

Is my question making sense?

More info for perhaps a different approach:
if I add a item to something, it won't console.log the item id if my forEach code is within the controller. I would need to refresh the page. 
my something is full of data that comes from my database, so in the view any data added to it won't be shown unless I refresh the page.
Simply showing the data with {{ }} will show it without having to refresh, but it seems that my code is limited if I use {{ }}. How do I work this out?

Comment: why do you want to console.log something from your template?

Comment: console.log is an example here

Comment: Can you show us on fiddle so that we could see what is not real time in your anguar code and what you did till now?

Comment: yeah my english is too crap and I've been having this issue for a long time now. I will make a clean new code to show my issue and post it

Answer (score 3):

in controller, bind function to scope property:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(something) {
    return something.toUpperCase();
};
```

in template call the scoped function:

```
<li ng-repeat="something in things">
    {{ doSomething(something) }}
</li>
```

Comment: thanks for trying bro my english is just not up to the standard to make other people understand what the hell I'm trying to say